# Network driver for Hyper-V restore from Windows Home Server

Tags: networking, restore, windows-home-server, drivers

I have backed up Windows Server 2008 running virtualized on Hyper-V to a [Windows Home Server 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/windowshomeserver/features.mspx) (I know I should have backed up the VHD instead).

Now **I need to restore the contents of the VM from WHS**. I have [created a restore CD ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=26881305-91CC-4F37-B1FC-3813C423DF2C&displaylang=en) and used it to create a new VM.

It all works as advertised up to the point where the restore process wants to load the network drivers (it only finds 4 disk drivers on the restore CD. but **no network drivers**). So I [created a virtual floppy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/f17a5448-853a-44e2-b606-2c4a918c98b8) and copied the contents of **'Home Server Drivers for Restore** onto it. But no luck! I have tried moving the 4 subdirectories into the root of the floppy, but that didn't work either. Finally, I started another instance of the WS 2008 to identify the network driver that the virtualized instance is using (**%WINDOWS%\system32\drivers\netvsc60.sys**) and copied that file onto the virtual floppy, without success.

Does anyone have any suggestions on **how to get networking working on a Hyper-V instance running off the Windows Home Server Restore CD**?

**UPDATE:**
As suggested by delenda, I have **added a legacy network adapter** to my VM, and indeed I now **get a network driver listed**! However, the WHS it still not found, even after entering the home server name manually.

PHS

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Legacy Adapter by right clicking on the VM then clicking settings -> Add Hardware -> Legacy Network Adapter

The 32/64 bit solution sounds good - that's the issue I had

Comment: I am trying your suggestion right now.

Can you elaborate a bit on what you had to do for the 32/64 bit issue? It appears that the restore is running as a 32-bit OS. How do I get my 64-bit VM back? Will I have to create a second VM and use the VHD of the first one to create it?

Comment: I have added the legacy network adapter like you suggested (thx!), and indeed it now shows 'Intel 21140-Based PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (Emulated)' as the single network device. After clicking 'Continue' and 'Next', it still doesn't find my WHS machine. I have tried to use the machine name directly, but it still doesn't find it. I can see the WHS machine is connected to my router (NETGEAR) and even shows the correct name.

Maybe the legacy network adapter is on the wrong subnet, or doesn't know about 192.168.0.1 (router).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the legacy network driver to the VM?

Comment: I don't see a way to do that other than putting it onto the virtual floppy which is what I did.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I've copied the 64-bit network driver (since that's what the to be restored instance of WS 2008 is), but maybe the restore VM is running 32-bit! Investigating ...

Answer (score 0):

Is your new legacy adapter associated with the correct network?  I don't think it uses the external adapter by default.